# Cómo mostrar registros de 2 tablas relacionadas de Room en recyclerview de android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, relación-1-n

estoy haciendo una aplicación en android con Room para la bd, tengo un entity llamado visita y otro llamado informe con una relación uno a muchos, una visita puede tener varios informes.

Ahora necesito mostrar en un recyclerview la lista de todos los informes con el índice y la geolocalización que está en la visita, pero no se de qué forma acceder a la información de la visita. Este es el código de los entities, la lista de informes y demás de mi app
Código de cada entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "informe")
public class Informe {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private int visitasId;
    private int consecutivo;
    private boolean primeraMuestra;
    private boolean segundaMuestra;
    private boolean terceraMuestra;
...
}

@Entity(tableName = "visitas")
public class Visita {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private String indice;
    private String geolocalizacion;
...
}


public class ListaInformesFragment extends Fragment  {
    private ListaInformesViewModel mViewModel;
    private ListaInformesFragmentBinding mBinding;
    private InformeCompraAdapter mListAdapter;

    public static ListaInformesFragment newInstance() {
        return new ListaInformesFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,
                R.layout.lista_informes_fragment, container, false);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(com.example.comprasmu.ui.informe.ListaInformesViewModel.class);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ListaInformesViewModel.class);
      
        mViewModel.cargarDetalles();
        mBinding.setLcviewModel(mViewModel);
        mBinding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        coordi
        setupListAdapter();
     
        mViewModel.getListas().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<InformeDao.Informe>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Informe> informeCompras) {
                mListAdapter.setInformeCompraList(informeCompras);
                mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupListAdapter() {
        mListAdapter = new InformeCompraAdapter(mViewModel,this);
        mBinding.detalleList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mBinding.detalleList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBinding.detalleList.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

    }
    ...
}
```

el viewmodel

```
public class ListaInformesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final InformeCompraRepositoryImpl repository;
    private LiveData<List<Informe>> listas;

    public ListaInformesViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new InformeCompraRepositoryImpl(application);
    }

    public void cargarDetalles(){
        listas = visitaRepo.getInformes();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Informe>> getListas() {
        return listas;
    }
}

public class InformeCompraAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InformeCompraAdapter.InformeCompraViewHolder> {
    private List<Informe> mInformeCompraList;
    private final ListaInformesViewModel mViewModel;
    public InformeCompraAdapter(ListaInformesViewModel viewModel, AdapterCallback callback) {
        mViewModel = viewModel;
        this.callback=callback;
    }

    public void setInformeCompraList(List<InformeCompraDao.InformeCompravisita> informesList) {
        mInformeCompraList = informesList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public InformeCompraAdapter.InformeCompraViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ListaInformeItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                        R.layout.lista_informe_item, parent, false);
        return new InformeCompraViewHolder(binding,callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull InformeCompraAdapter.InformeCompraViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.binding.setDetalle(mInformeCompraList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mInformeCompraList == null ? 0 : mInformeCompraList.size();
    }

    static class InformeCompraViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ListaInformeItemBinding binding;

        public InformeCompraViewHolder(ListaInformeItemBinding binding,AdapterCallback callback) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }
        ...
    }
```

el layout lista_informe_item.xml

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
<data >
    <variable name="detalle"
        type="com.example.comprasmu.data.dao.Informe"></variable>
</data>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/ldcardview"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="81dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="199dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtliindice"
                style="@style/textolista1"
                android:layout_width="178dp"
                android:layout_height="17dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@{detalle.indice}"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/txtfecha"
                  style="@style/textolista1"
                  android:layout_width="194dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                  android:text="@{sdf.format(detalle.consecutivo)}"
                  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.142" />

                 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txttienda"
                style="@style/textolista1"
                android:layout_width="178dp"
                android:layout_height="17dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="@{detalle.geolocalizacion}"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtfecha" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Es en el layout anterior donde quiero mostrar la geolocalizacion de la visita.
Probé hacer una consulta usando un ejemplo de android

```
 @RawQuery(observedEntities = Informevisita.class)
    LiveData<List<Informevisita>> getInformesVisitaByFiltros(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
    public static class Informevisita {
        public String indice;
        public Date fecha;
        public String clienteNombre;
        public String plantaNombre;
        public int estatusinforme;
        public String nombreTienda;
        public int idinforme;
    }
```

Pero me manda un error que para usar RawQuery y observedEntities  Informevisita tiene que ser un entity.
Entonces ya no se qué hacer, espero haberme explicado gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues como nadie me respondió y ya pude resolverlo lo comparto por si a alguien le sirve.
Utilicé un @DatabaseView donde hago el inner join de las dos tablas que necesitaba informe y visita con los campos que necesito y creo el Dao siguiendo este tutorial https://nhkarthick.medium.com/android-room-database-with-a-view-a9b8a0c20199

Después hago mi Rawquery con los parametros dinámicos sobre la vista ya creada.

Saludos